# iPhone input textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hi all
Im quite new to iPhone development, I see many applications using a form UI like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/znEex.png

first i thought it was a standard control from the UIKit, but after some searching it doesn't seem to be.

Im interested in knowing if theres an easy way to create this kind of label to the left and input field to the right kind of cell?

Im guessing this design is created with Table Views and each input is defined as a UITableViewCell.
I know i can just create a custom UITableViewCell, but i thought that since i see so many applications using this kind of input there must a standard control or an easy way of implementing it?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way than using custom UITableViewCell to create such UI widget.

and for user input you need to add either `UITextView` or `UIFieldView`to your custom cell.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `UITextField`; there is no such thing as `UIFieldView`. And you should never use a `UITextView` inside an instance of `UITableViewCell`, because `UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, and scroll views are not designed to be nested (the table view itself is an instance of a  subclass of `UITableView`).

Comment: @ jlehr Yes i meant 'UITextField' , In case what happened if you require a multiline input text control in UItableView. What are you going to use for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you will need a `UIViewController` as your base with a `UIImageView` and a `UITableView`.

There's also a lot of subclassing you would need to do to get it fairly the same.